# HP Proliant 360 video disabled in BIOS

Tags: bios, video

I was asked to work on a Proliant 360 Server. I can boot it up and remotely log onto it and it appears to work perfectly. However, there's no video locally from either the front or rear VGA ports. It appears that the video is turned off in BIOS? I can't access the BIOS remotely (unless I'm missing something. I know virtually nothing about servers, though I have decades of experience on computers in general).
How can I enable the video so I see something on the screen when I boot it up? Do I have to reset the BIOS? I already discovered how to do that, just don't want to use that hammer if a better tool is available.
Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: Press F9 at bootup, this'll get you into the BIOS setup.

Comment: Does it have a dedicated Graphics Card? Does it have iLO enabled you could access the BIOS via this.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset the BIOS to defaults.**

If you're working on a server of unknown origin, it completely makes sense to reset the system to its default settings. Otherwise you end up with weird things like people disabling the VGA ports...

Comment: If for some reason you don't want to or can't reset the bios, you can get into it at boot using the video redirection or serial redirection features of an iLO (if you have access to it and don't need to reset that as well). Other than that, just reset it all as ewwhite said.